# Cordova angular-oauth2 generating token error?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui, oauth-2.0

I am trying to build an android app using cordova along with onsen-ui. The app makes HTTP requests to a django web service to fetch data, which has implemented oauth2 to verify users.

I have currently implemented oauth from my app using angular-oauth2 library. This works fine while running from local server. But when the app is built into an apk, the HTTP requests no longer contain the auth token. Hence my request no longer get authenticated.

Comment: Can you show us the error message if you are getting one?

Comment: no there's no error message i only put up an alert which shoots when there is no token released

Comment: Do you have content security policy declared etc?

Comment: no there is no content policy declared

Comment: Could you try if declaring it properly solves the problem?

Comment: ya i tried both didn't work